# Using ajax to store textarea info into database. Works fine unless I edit textarea in ANY way.. Info still gets stored but XMLHTTP never closes

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, textarea

Basically I call a function when user clicks save, this function takes the content from textarea and passes it to a php file that adds it to the database. 
I have a few js functions I use, one for switching between content and another for saving it.
Anyway if i just click save without editing anything in the textarea, then everything works fine. However if I edit the text in any way (Even removing a letter and adding it back again) parts of the functions stop working. The part that is responsible for modifying content. I have marked the part that stops working.

I have tested to see whether it was the content I was passing.. it was not.
Now it seems like the textarea itself gets messed up and wont show new information.
I tested it by putting 2 textareas, one that holds the content to be stored and is edited, and another just to display changes (changes which stop working on the main text area).

```
function saveContent() {
    document.getElementById("editing").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("observing").style.display = '';
    document.getElementById("contentArea").readOnly = true;


    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        alert("first if");
    }
    else // code for IE6, IE5
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        //alert("second if");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //alert(xmlhttp.readyState+" : "+xmlhttp.status);
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert("finished");
            document.getElementById("contentArea").innerHTML = "working"; < ---- * * THIS PART STOPS WORKING IF I MODIFY THE TEXTAREA IN ANY WAY * *
        }
    }
    //var Content = document.getElementById("contentArea");
    var content = "contenttt";
    //alert(content);
    xmlhttp.open("get", "saveContent.php?q=" + content_id + "&content=" + content, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}​
```

Comment: What type of element is `contentArea`? Which ID is the textarea?

Comment: depending on AndrewR's question answer. if `contentArea` is textarea, shouldn't it be `.val` instead lf `.innerHTML`?

Answer (score 0):

In case the comments given don't solve your problem, a few suggestions what to work on.

Firstly, maybe the problem is that you're using content variable with capital C, or maybe that's just here. But I know that chrome tends to mess up ajax calls with undefined variables.

```
//var Content = document.getElementById("contentArea");
var content = "contenttt";
```

Secondly, send text variables in POST.

```
xmlhttp.Open("POST","saveContent.php?q=" + content_id, false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("content=" + content);
```

Lastly, consider using **JQuery**. There is reason why it is so popular. It is easy to use, problems like these rarely occur and works on all known browser.

```
$.post('saveContent.php', {"q": content_id, "content": $('#contentArea').val()}, function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: personnal question, `alert(data);` will output what saveContent.php echo?

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have tried using POST to send the variables, as well as using lower case variable it didn't help.
In the end I fixed it by using "$('#contentArea').val(xmlhttp.responseText);" to modify the textarea, rather than "document.getElementById("contentArea").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;"
Still not sure why that was like that but at least it works now.

Comment: 1) Yes alert the will output the echo. 2) Switching to JQuery is an overall suggestion, there has to be a solution without it obviously, i assume than the problem wasn't that you were using innerHTML on a textarea